# Dynamically change outcome of JOIN using select parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have a select query I am using that involves a join for a grid view display:

```
SELECT [Theme].[Name], [ThemeType].[Type] 
FROM [Theme] 
Left Outer Join [ThemeType] ON [Theme].[ThemeTypeId] = [ThemeType].[PK_ThemeType] 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN [ThemeType].[Type] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, [ThemeType].[Type]
```

This currently returns everything. I need the ability to show no null returns or only nullr eturns as well and from the same query which will dynamically get different inputs via SelectParameters.

Basically, I have a drop down list that has 3 options, all which is correctly shown above, but I need a select parameter to change value of an input to result in the 3 options.

I tried:

```
SELECT [Theme].[Name], [ThemeType].[Type] FROM [Theme] 
Left Outer Join [ThemeType] ON [Theme].[ThemeTypeId] = [ThemeType].[PK_ThemeType] 
WHERE [Theme].[ThemeTypeId] LIKE '%' 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN [ThemeType].[Type] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, [ThemeType].[Type]
```

Where the % would be changable but all this shows is the not nulls....

Here is the datasource:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource6" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [Theme].[Name], [ThemeType].[Type] FROM [Theme] Left Outer Join [ThemeType] ON [Theme].[ThemeTypeId] = [ThemeType].[PK_ThemeType] ORDER BY CASE WHEN [ThemeType].[Type] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, [ThemeType].[Type]">
     <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="changeParam" Type="String" />
</SelectParameters>
```

Comment: This is kind of a hack but: `WHERE COALESCE([ThemeTypeId], 'this_is_null') LIKE '%this_is_null%'` for only null.  Then just change the string to be `LIKE '%[0-9]%'` for non-null and `LIKE '%'` for everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't figure out how to do it the way I wanted but I took an alternative approach and did it programatically. I have a method that fires when my drop down options menu fires and depending on the selection the gridview gets a different select query.

```
protected void viewThemeTypeAssociationsDropDown_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (viewThemeTypeAssociationsDropDown.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        SqlDataSource6.SelectCommand = "SELECT [Theme].[Name], [ThemeType].[Type] FROM [Theme] Left Outer Join [ThemeType] ON [Theme].[ThemeTypeId] = [ThemeType].[PK_ThemeType] ORDER BY [Theme].[Name] ASC";
    }
    else if (viewThemeTypeAssociationsDropDown.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        SqlDataSource6.SelectCommand = "SELECT [Theme].[Name], [ThemeType].[Type] FROM [Theme], [ThemeType] WHERE [Theme].[ThemeTypeId] = [ThemeType].[PK_ThemeType] ORDER BY [Theme].[Name] ASC";
    }
    else
    {
        SqlDataSource6.SelectCommand = "SELECT [Theme].[Name], [ThemeType].[Type] FROM [Theme] Left Outer Join [ThemeType] ON [Theme].[ThemeTypeId] = [ThemeType].[PK_ThemeType] WHERE [Theme].[ThemeTypeId] IS NULL ORDER BY [Theme].[Name] ASC";
    }
}
```

You have to completely remove selectcommand="" from the Sqldatasource for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

Update your where clause to check for the value of the parameter or for where the parameter `IS NULL`; `[Theme].[ThemeTypeId] = @changeParam OR @changeParam IS NULL`

```
SELECT
     [Theme].[Name],
     [ThemeType].[Type]
FROM
     [Theme] LEFT OUTER JOIN [ThemeType]
          ON
     [Theme].[ThemeTypeId] = [ThemeType].[PK_ThemeType] 
WHERE
     [Theme].[ThemeTypeId] = @changeParam
           OR
      (COALESCE([Theme].[ThemeTypeId], N'NULL') = N'NULL' AND @changeParam IS NULL)
ORDER BY
     CASE WHEN [ThemeType].[Type] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
     [ThemeType].[Type]
```

---

Here's a short sample to try out to see if it works as you want.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
(
    Theme       nvarchar(100),
    ThemeType   nvarchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO
    @t
    (
        Theme,
        ThemeType
    )
--I use the union since I am working on SQL Server 2005
SELECT
    N'1',
    N'1111'
UNION
SELECT
    N'1',
    N'----'
UNION
SELECT
    N'2',
    N'2222'
UNION
SELECT
    null,
    N'2222'

DECLARE @s  nvarchar(100)
SET @s = N'1' -- change this line for the criteria
--SET @s = null

SELECT
    *
FROM
    @t
WHERE
    Theme = @s
        OR
    (COALESCE(Theme, N'NULL') = N'NULL' AND @s IS NULL)
```

Comment: This can return all items or non-null items, but not null ThemeTypeId only (Of course maybe ThemeTypeId isn't a nullable column, I couldn't figure that one out).

Comment: I missed that in the original question. I have updated my answer. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: I still can't get this to return "only" null ThemeTypeId.

Comment: Did you run the sample SQL that I posted in my answer with `SET @s = null`?

Comment: `set @s = null;` returned all rows.

Comment: That's truly odd. I ran it myself and I got the expected results.

Comment: Is it possible you changed this line `(COALESCE(@changeParam, N'NULL') = N'NULL' AND @changeParam IS NULL)` vs what's posted?  Maybe first @changeParam was a column?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34273/discussion-between-joefletch-and-ebyrob)

Answer (score 1):

As I'd tried to point out in my comment, `COALESCE` allows what you want...

```
SELECT [Theme].[Name], [ThemeType].[Type] FROM [Theme] 
Left Outer Join [ThemeType]
             ON [Theme].[ThemeTypeId] = [ThemeType].[PK_ThemeType] 
WHERE COALESCE([Theme].[ThemeTypeId], 'null') LIKE '%' 
ORDER BY CASE 
         WHEN [ThemeType].[Type] IS NULL 
         THEN 1 
         ELSE 0 
         END, [ThemeType].[Type]
```

You'll either have a ThemeTypeId that's an integer or a string consisting of 'null' which you can compare with `LIKE` e.g.: `'null'`, `'%'`, OR `'%[0-9]%'`.